# Where can I go to ask programming professionals about career advice?

Tags: discussion

I am a junior Java developer and would like to receive some career advice from programming professionals.

Programmers Stack Exchange doesn't allow personal career advice, but where should I go to ask about it?

Comment: Another alternative: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/can-i-ask-career-advice-questions?rq=1

Comment: And http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980 (the related reading section)